# How to set pts, dts and duration in ffmpeg library?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, duration, dts, pts

I want to pack some compressed video packets(h.264) to ".mp4" container.
One word, Muxing, no decoding and no encoding.
And I have no idea how to set pts, dts and duration.

1. I get the packets with "pcap" library.
2. I removed headers before compressed video data show up. e.g. Ethernet, VLAN.
3. I collected data until one frame and decoded it for getting information of data. e.g. width, height. (I am not sure that it is necessary)
4. I initialized output context, stream and codec context.
5. I started to receive packets with "pcap" library again. (now for muxing)
6. I made one frame and put that data in AVPacket structure.
7. I try to set PTS, DTS and duration. (I think here is wrong part, not sure though)

*7-1. At the first frame, I saved time(msec) with packet header structure.

*7-2. whenever I made one frame, I set parameters like this : PTS(current time - start time), DTS(same PTS value), duration(current PTS - before PTS)

I think it has some error because :

1. I don't know how far is suitable long for dts from pts.
2. At least, I think duration means how long time show this frame from now to next frame, so It should have value(next PTS - current PTS), but I can not know the value next PTS at that time.

It has I-frame only.

```
// make input context for decoding

AVFormatContext *&ic = gInputContext;

ic = avformat_alloc_context();

AVCodec *cd = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

AVStream *st = avformat_new_stream(ic, cd);

AVCodecContext *cc = st->codec;

avcodec_open2(cc, cd, NULL);

// make packet and decode it after collect packets is be one frame

gPacket.stream_index = 0;

gPacket.size    = gPacketLength[0];

gPacket.data    = gPacketData[0];

gPacket.pts     = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

gPacket.dts     = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

gPacket.flags   = AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

avcodec_decode_video2(cc, gFrame, &got_picture, &gPacket);

// I checked automatically it initialized after "avcodec_decode_video2"

// put some info that I know that not initialized

cc->time_base.den   = 90000;

cc->time_base.num   = 1;

cc->bit_rate    = 2500000;

cc->gop_size    = 1;

// make output context with input context

AVFormatContext *&oc = gOutputContext;

avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, NULL, filename);

AVFormatContext *&ic = gInputContext;

AVStream *ist = ic->streams[0];

AVCodecContext *&icc = ist->codec;

AVStream *ost = avformat_new_stream(oc, icc->codec);

AVCodecContext *occ = ost->codec;

avcodec_copy_context(occ, icc);

occ->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

avio_open(&(oc->pb), filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

// repeated part for muxing

AVRational Millisecond = { 1, 1000 };

gPacket.stream_index = 0;

gPacket.data = gPacketData[0];

gPacket.size = gPacketLength[0];

gPacket.pts = av_rescale_rnd(pkthdr->ts.tv_sec * 1000 /

    + pkthdr->ts.tv_usec / 1000 /

    - gStartTime, Millisecond.den, ost->time_base.den, /

    (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));

gPacket.dts = gPacket.pts;

gPacket.duration = gPacket.pts - gPrev;

gPacket.flags = AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

gPrev = gPacket.pts;

av_interleaved_write_frame(gOutputContext, &gPacket);
```

Expected and actual results is a .mp4 video file that can play.

Comment: Your process seems correct in theory. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Thank you for comments. I solved it. the problem was that I have to set duration time stamp, not pts.

Comment: @hslee, so can you write how did you solve it more clearly? So leaving pts and dts as `AV_NOPTS_VALUE` is okay?